# program adding numbers doesn't show any output

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I have a problem with an "add calculator".
Valgrind reports no memory errors, no errors from compiler but the program doesn't show any output despite the printf - "Base is ".

All pointers, and variables are (n my opinion) correctly initialized.

`getnum` function gets a number, returns a pointer to char - `char *`,
`add` function processes two numbers as strings, `return`s `result` which is a pointer to char (`char *`) as well.

I don't know whether the problem is memory allocation or procedures connected to processing arrays...

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(A,B) ((A)>(B) ? (A) : (B))

char *getnum(FILE *infile, int base)
{
    int len = 10;
    int c;
    int pos = 0;
    char *num = NULL;
    char *tmpnum = NULL;

    num = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);

    while (((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) && (isalnum(c))) {

        if (isdigit(c)) {
           /* irrelevant*/
        }
        else if (isalpha(c)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Wrong base, expected 16\n");
            free(num);
            return NULL;

        }
        if (pos >= len) {
            /*realloc*/
        }
    }

    return num;           
}
```

---

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *infile = NULL;
    char *number1 = NULL;
    char *number2 = NULL;
    char *result = NULL;
    int base, i, j = 0, length, count = 0;


    infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    base  = atoi(argv[2]);
    while (!feof(infile)) {
        number1 = getnum(infile, base);

        number2 = getnum(infile, base);

        break;
    }
    printf("Base is %d\n", base);
    result = add(number1, number2, base);

    length = strlen(result);
    for (i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
        if (result[i] == '0') {
            count++;
        }
    }

    for (j = i; j == (length - 1); j++) {
        printf("Result is: %s\n", &result[j]);
        break;
    }
    free(result);
    result = NULL;
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to work it out for the past 4 hours and can't find a mistake.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger, setting a break-point at the printf() call that you see and then step through your code?

Comment: What is your test input?

Comment: @timrau in input.txt I put two numbers in decimal system. Invoked the program with ./name input.txt 10 As said previously I only get Base is 10.

Comment: @timrau Thanks to You and Matthew Slattery problem is already solved. BUT I have a question for the future: gdb informed program had run without problems. So how to use it to launch a "correctly" working code through gdb. I had only two steps from pushing start and gdb ended testing, exited normally...

Comment: @PeterKowalski You should set a break point. Otherwise, gdb simply let the program run through. Try `break main` before pushing start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one severe typo near the end of `main()`.

```
for (j = i; j == (length - 1); j++) {
/*            ^^ SHOULD BE <= */
    printf("Result is: %s\n", &result[j]);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
    if (result[i] == '0') {
        count++;
    }
}
if (count == length) {
    printf("Result is 0\n");
    free(result);
    result = NULL;                     /* arguable */
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}
for (i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
    if (result[i] != '0') {
        break;
    }
}
for (j = i; j == (length - 1); j++) {
    printf("Result is: %s\n", &result[j]);
    break;
}
```

1. Instead of counting the total number of zeroes in the output number, and then counting the number of leading zeroes again, why not combine the two?
2. What is the last loop about?  It's not even really a loop - it will execute once if `i` is `length - 1`, or not at all if not (presumably you're hitting the latter case in your test input).

e.g.

```
for (count = 0; count < length; count++) {
    if (result[count] != '0')
        break;
}
if (count == length) {
    printf("Result is 0\n");
    free(result);
    result = NULL;                     /* arguable */
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}
printf("Result is: %s\n", &result[count]);
```